# VueJS app can't access protected API endpoint on mobile browser

Tags: django, vue.js, jwt, axios, vuex

I'm having an issue with my Vue app regarding usage on mobile browsers. I have a protected API route on a Django backend that uses JWT for authentication/permission. When I authenticate, I save the JWT to localStorage and Vuex and pass it along as a header on each request (using axios) from the Vuex store. This all works fine on my laptop, but it does not work when accessing my site on mobile. I see 401 unauthorized error codes in my logs when accessing the site with my phone (iOS 12), so I assume that token is not being added as a header. Here's the code that I use to attach the header:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../store';

const apiCall = axios.create();

apiCall.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      // Take the token from the state and attach it to the request's headers
      config.headers.Authorization = `JWT ${store.getters.getToken}`;
    }
    return config
  },
  error => {
    Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

export default apiCall;
```

Here are my dev dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
```

Is there something that I need to add to my `devDependencies` so that I can access `Posts` from mobile devices?

Comment: Try using cookies instead of localStorage.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code to obtain JWT token. Are you testing desktop and mobile locally or deployed on remote servers? Environment variables for API endpoint or possibly CORS headers may play a role here. Best to preview the request headers and responses with Inspect Network tab with your browser to ensure that request to fetch JWT token is going to a right endpoint and it’s not being blocked by CORS policy before assuming its being stored properly. Another thing is that I usually see “Bearer “ before the token string.

Comment: @mal Sure, the source code is here: [https://gitlab.com/briancaffey/verbose-equals-true](https://gitlab.com/briancaffey/verbose-equals-true). I have deployed the site to [https://verbose-equals-true.tk](https://verbose-equals-true.tk). I agree that it could be CORS (I currently do not have it enabled in my Django app), but I'm still unsure as to why I would be able to access the restricted endpoint on my laptop and not mobile. I have set `JWT` before the token string. Also, testing locally on mobile does not work.

Comment: @briancaffey I looked at the GitLab link, but once I submit the login form with default placeholders admin/password I get response 400.

Comment: @mal Hi, thanks for looking at the link. I have update the site with some demo users to choose from. This should reproduce this issue I'm having: the site has no problems on a desktop browser, but I'm unable to access protected API routes because the token doesn't seem to be passed along on mobile browsers.